# Is it possible to move the screen without connecting in nav_graph?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-bottomnavigationview

I am using BottomNavigation.
The transition from the screen of menu A to another screen, not the screen transition from menu A to another, is as follows.

menu A(fragment) -> B screen(fragment) -> C screen(fragment) -> B screen(fragment)

I hooked up these screen transitions in `nav_graph`

I am using `BottomNavigation`.
The transition from the screen of `menu A` to another screen, not the screen transition from menu A to another, is as follows.

menu A(fragment) -> B screen(fragment) -> C screen(fragment) -> D screen(fragment)

I hooked up these screen transitions in `nav_graph`

However, the screen transition from `D` to `C` was not connected, but it was possible to switch the screen using `view.findNavController.navigate()`.

I thought transitioning the screen was impossible without connecting to the `nav_graph`.

How is this possible?

***UPDATED***

***nav_graph.xml***

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<navigation xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/nav_graph"
    app:startDestination="@id/calendar">
    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/calendar"
        android:name="com.example.writeweight.fragment.CalendarFragment"
        android:label="fragment_calendar"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_calendar" >
    </fragment>
    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/list"
        android:name="com.example.writeweight.fragment.WorkoutListFragment"
        android:label="fragment_workout_list"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_workout_list" />
    <!-- menu A fragment -->
    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/write_home"
        android:name="com.example.writeweight.fragment.WriteRoutineHomeFragment"
        android:label="fragment_write_routine_home"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_write_routine_home" >
        <action
            android:id="@+id/action_write_home_to_bodyPartDialog"
            app:destination="@id/bodyPartDialog" />
    </fragment>
    
    <!-- B screen -->
    <dialog
        android:id="@+id/bodyPartDialog"
        android:name="com.example.writeweight.fragment.BodyPartDialogFragment"
        android:label="BodyPartDialogFragment"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_body_part_dialog">
        <action
            android:id="@+id/action_bodyPartDialog_to_write"
            app:destination="@id/write"/>
    </dialog>
    
    <!-- C screen -->
    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/write"
        android:name="com.example.writeweight.fragment.WritingRoutineFragment"
        android:label="WritingRoutineFragment"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_writing_routine">
        <action
            android:id="@+id/action_write_to_bodyPartDialog"
            app:destination="@id/bodyPartDialog" />
        <argument
            android:name="title"
            app:argType="string"
            android:defaultValue="" />
    </fragment>
    
    <!-- D screen   -->
    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/workoutListTabFragment"
        android:name="com.example.writeweight.fragment.WorkoutListTabFragment"
        android:label="fragment_workout_list_tab"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_workout_list_tab" />
</navigation>
```

Comment: Are you sure? And is `D` a global destination?

Comment: Yes. I implemented the screen transition code in the `adapter`.

And what is the global destination?

I'll attach my `nav_graph` code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per the [Navigate using ID documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-navigate#id):

> [navigate(int)](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/navigation/NavController#navigate(kotlin.Int)) takes the resource ID of either an action or a destination.

So both directly navigating to any destination is possible (by using the ID of the destination) and navigating via an action is supported.

The documentation goes on to say:

> Note: When navigating using IDs, **we strongly recommend using actions where possible.** Actions provide additional information in your navigation graph, visually showing how your destinations connect to each other. By creating actions, you can replace resource IDs with [Safe Args-generated operations](https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-pass-data#Safe-args), providing additional compile-time safety. By using an action, you can also animate transitions between the destinations. For more information, see [Animate transitions between destinations](https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-animate-transitions).

Comment: `we strongly recommend using actions where possible` means to put the `ID` of the `action tag` in `navigate()`, not the `ID` of the `fragment`? Or do you mean use [this](https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-navigate#example-safeargs)?

Comment: Yes, if you're using the `navigate(int)` version, you should use the ID of an action. Safe Args is better still

Comment: Thanks. If so, I have a question for your answer. When using `navigate(int)` instead of `safe args action`, why use the `action tag's ID` instead of the `fragment ID`?

As a result of my experiments, there was no problem with screen switching.

Comment: oh sorry. Is the part I asked the question already in the part you answered? (`When navigating using IDs, we strongly recommend using actions where possible. Actions provide additional information in your navigation graph, visually showing how your destinations connect to each other. `)

Comment: Right, the visual representation and the ability to swap out IDs entirely for Safe Args generated code is what you'd gain by defining actions that only use `app:destination`, like your example does.

Comment: In summary, when using `navigate(int)`, both`resource ID` and `action tag ID` are possible, but it is better to use `action ID`, but the best method is to use `Safe Args` created by defining `action`.

Is that right?

Comment: Thank you so much. Thanks for always helping